# Matrix representation of semi direct product of finite groups

Tags: representation-theory, semidirect-product

Consider I given finite groups $T, R$ with representations act on the same finite vector space $V$, $\rho_T$ and $\rho_R$. Let's also consider that I given a group homomorphism $\phi: R\to Aut(T)$, $T$ is normal under conjugation with $R$. Then how can I construct matrix representation for $G=T\rtimes_{\phi}R$ acting on $V$?

For direct product it is <s>just product of representations $\rho_T$ and $\rho_R$</s>, I can do as following:

$$
(t,r)(t',r') = (tt', rr') = (tt',1)(1, rr') \\
\rho_G((t,r)(t',r')) = \rho_{G}(tt',1)\rho_{G}(1, rr')
$$
So, I can define action on $V\oplus V$.Hence it is enough to define action on each group on $V$, but I given them.

But for semi direct I should some how incorporate $\phi$. Also as example of such construction is Affine group, but I can not figure out how to use it (as inspiration). (So if it is possible I would like to first see how construction works for Affine group and than try to generalise)

What did I try.

One simple example is to consider $r^{-1}tr = r^{-1}rt = t$, than
representation $\rho(G)$ is product of representations $\rho_T$ and $\rho_R$.

I have following constrains on representation $\rho_G$ to satisfy:

$$
\rho_{G}(t) = \rho_T(t), \\
\rho_{G}(r) = \rho_R(r), \\
\rho_{G}(r^{-1}tr) = \rho_T(\phi(r)t).
$$

Let's start from a simple case: consider both T,R is cyclic group with $t^n=e$ and $r^m=e$, than acting on basis $v_1,\dots,v_K$ I can write:

$$
\rho_T(t) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{K}|v_{t\cdot k}\rangle\langle v_k|,\,
\rho_R(r) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{K}|v_{r\cdot k}\rangle\langle v_k|,
$$
where actions over indexes are permutations that satisfies $t^n=e$ and $r^m=e$.

In order to satisfy $\rho_{G}(r^{-1}tr) = \rho_T(\phi(r)t)$ I can try to construct something like this:

$$
\phi(r)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}|t^{\phi_r(n)}\rangle \langle t|,
$$
where $\phi_r(n)$ is a permutation. And here I am stuck.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Consider the case $T,R$ both abelian, $\dim(V)=1$. Also, the direct product doesn't work as you describe.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I don't see why unfortunate. I elaborate on direct products on question.

Comment: If $G$ has a $2$-dimensional representation then $G\times G$ has a $4$-dimensional representation, not a $2$-dimensional one. Unless you want one of the factors to act trivially, but then of course the problem is easy to solve.

Comment: It seems for me (very informally) than on one pole we have direct product, where indeed, we can do nothing but direct sum. On other pole, if  I take such $\phi$ that $T$ and $R$ commute  then representation is product of representations? May be I wrong again. But may be let's stick to your example. I consider even simpler, let's $T$, $R$ be cyclic. So I can choose a basis $v$ of $V$ such that $t v = v$, and $r v =\lambda v$. But what to do next?

Comment: This is Clifford theory. Understanding how to construct representations of $G$ from those of $T$ and $R$ is the entire subject.

Comment: I see, thank you. Is there any specific way for semi-direct product of two cyclic groups? Should be much simpler

Comment: Such groups are called metacyclic. For example the group $C_{p^2}\rtimes C_p$ has representations of dimensions $1$ ($p^2$ of these) and $p$ ($p-1$ of these).

Comment: Thank you! Could you may be recommend a very gentle introduction to the Clifford theory?